# monitor printing

Tags: c#, .net, printing

Is it possible to monitor all printing acctivities from service installed locally for example save all files which are going to be printed on any printer and save them to file in any format ?

Im talking about .net solutions

thanks for any answers,
bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make a [Print Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686805%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).